# How to accept and parse a csv w/ Jackson in Spring Rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

What do I need to do to be able to upload a csv file and have it parsed automatically with Jackson? Just using the below I get "Unsupported Media Type", which makes me think I'm missing a configuration.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class Uploader {
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String create(@RequestBody List<MyDataType> myFile) {
        return myFile.toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "item1", "item2" })
public class MyDataType {
    public String item1;
    public String item2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a REST-API, file uploads are usually done as a multipart form data request to ensure you can also pass i.e. JSON data along with your file. So you probably need to add the media type to your `@PostMapping` annotation like `@PostMapping(consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})`.

Then you can have the file injected in your controller method and parse the CSV there.

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public List<MyDataType> create(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(MyDataType.class).withHeader().withColumnSeparator(';');
    MappingIterator<MyDataType> parsedData = csvMapper.readerWithSchemaFor(MyDataType.class)
            .with(schema)
            .readValues(new String(file.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    return parsedData.readAll();
}
```

You may also need to add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you will need :-
Dependency :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then at the controller

```
@PostMapping("/uploadCSVFile")
public Response uploadSingleCSVFile(@RequestParam("csvfile") MultipartFile csvfile) {

    Response response = new Response();

InputStream file = csvfile.getInputStream();
List<Object> lstCustomers = ApacheCommonsCsvUtil.parseCsvFile(file);

    }
```

Code is just for reference please format and test.